# Merge multiple object values of array into 1

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my array:

```
[ 
  'Ddy1QVOAO6SIvB8LfAE8Z0Adj4H3',
  'hBwNVTlluaagZ5Fqd6f0Ws3Vxtn1',
  'Ddy1QVOAO6SIvB8LfAE8Z0Adj4H3',
  'Ddy1QVOAO6SIvB8LfAE8Z0Adj4H3'
]
```

If want to check, if it has similar objects then I want it to be merged into one and return me array as:

```
[
  'Ddy1QVOAO6SIvB8LfAE8Z0Adj4H3',
  'hBwNVTlluaagZ5Fqd6f0Ws3Vxtn1',
]
```

How is this possible in JavaScript or TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Set to remove duplicate values :

```js
array = [ 'Ddy1QVOAO6SIvB8LfAE8Z0Adj4H3',
  'hBwNVTlluaagZ5Fqd6f0Ws3Vxtn1',
  'Ddy1QVOAO6SIvB8LfAE8Z0Adj4H3',
  'Ddy1QVOAO6SIvB8LfAE8Z0Adj4H3' ];
  
var result = [...new Set(array)];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this a relatively recent addition to JavaScript?